# Automatically detect nearby Bluetooth devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

**Assumptions**

The Android device A paired with other Bluetooth devices B, C, D.

**Problem**

How to implement Android app on device A that can detect directly availability of devices B, C, D without scanning all devices.
E.g. when taking B, C devices near to A, A can detect that B, C are existing and D is not available. After that device C is out of the range, it can detect that C is not available...

Thank you very much!

Comment: Bluetooth comes in two main versions: [Classic Bluetooth](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth) and [Bluetooth Low Energy](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le) what research have you done?

Comment: I want to research to both of cases. However, the major case is working with Bluetooth of smart phones.

Answer (score 0):

You can get already paired devices using [getBondedDevices()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#getBondedDevices()).